# vw and vh doesn't seem to work properly on google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to create a mobile site where the body fills the entire viewport.
I've written the following in the styelsheet

```
html, body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

however, when using the chrome dev tool's responsive mode, css starts doing weird things.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geuck.png)

Is this simply a browser bug, or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile browser do some automatic resizing and some other stuff. You could try to add the following line to your page in the head element:

```html
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>
```

This line sets a setting on the viewport, namely that the width of the viewport should always equal the device width.

Comment: I do have the meta tag set already. The page actually displays correctly on normal browser window, but starts to fail when using chrome’s device emulator. This is the first time it happened to me, so I was wondering if something I did was although correct, but a bad practice that causes bugs in some cases. Thanks for the reply though